# How to add blank line in email body?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to update email body but entire body is coming in one line.
[image]

How to add blank line in email body like below?

> Dear Kalpesh,
>
> Your enthusiasm and ability to demonstrate & deliver your set goals has resulted in a significant increase in productivity and profitability.

```vb
Sub CreateEmails()

    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceWorksheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    With sourceWorksheet
         lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim rowIndex As Long

    For rowIndex = 2 To lastRow 'start at the second row

        Dim MItem As Object
        Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

        Dim strbody As String
    
        strbody = "Dear" & " " & sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "A").Value & "," & vbNewLine & _
          "Your enthusiasm and ability to demonstrate & deliver your set goals has resulted in a significant increase in productivity and profitability."
              
        With MItem
            .To = sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "E").Value
            .CC = sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "F").Value
            'Will pull in all email address in Row C as separate emails
            .Subject = "MIP Rating - Sep'22"
            .HTMLBody = strbody
            .display

        End With[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    Next rowIndex
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply html format and set the `BodyFormat` property of the mail item to `olFormatHTML`.

```
Dim body_ As String
    body_= "<p> Dear " & sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "A").Value & "</p>" & _
           "<p> Your enthusiasm and ability to demonstrate & deliver your set goals has resulted in a significant increase in productivity and profitability.</p>" 

.BodyFormat = 2 'olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = "<html><head></head><body>" & body_ & "</body></html>"
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are using HTML body then Use break tag `<br>` instead of `VBNewLine`. See below code.

So, change will be made to this line

```
strbody = "Dear" & " " & sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "A").Value & ", <br><br>" & _
          "Your enthusiasm and ability to demonstrate & deliver your set goals has resulted in a significant increase in productivity and profitability."
```

Full Macro will be-

```
Sub CreateEmails()
    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim MItem As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    
    Set sourceWorksheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With sourceWorksheet
         lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    For rowIndex = 2 To lastRow 'start at the second row
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    strbody = "Dear" & " " & sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "A").Value & ", <br><br>" & _
              "Your enthusiasm and ability to demonstrate & deliver your set goals has resulted in a significant increase in productivity and profitability."
              
        With MItem
            .To = sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "E").Value
            .CC = sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "F").Value
            'Will pull in all email address in Row C as separate emails
            .Subject = "MIP Rating - Sep'22"
            .HTMLBody = strbody
            .display

        End With
    Next rowIndex
    End Sub
```

Comment: How to add additional line to the body, I tried using <br> for few more lines but it did not worked

Comment: What happen when you run my macro?

Comment: strbody = "Dear" & " " & sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "A").Value & ", <br><br>" & _
                  "Your enthusiasm and ability to demonstrate & deliver your set goals has resulted in a significant increase in productivity and profitability." & _
                "3rd line" & _
                "4th Line"

Comment: getting all in one line again